# Getting only default database in Hive while connecting it through java

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, hiveql, default

I am able to make the connection to Hive remote server through jdbc, however, while listing databases I am only getting default database

```
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "show databases";
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
        System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
```